# Liferay: How can I set a specific layout for Terms of use content, the page shown after an user registered

Tags: liferay

Using Liferay 6.2, I try to workaround to set a specific layout for the Terms of use, shown after an user registered to the portal, and also Verify Email Address page after the user clicked "Agree" under URL /c/portal/....

I would like to have these pages showing with a look and feel I created. For example, I have created a layout called "1_column_white" in the theme I am using for this site and would like to assign to these pages (Terms of use and Verify Email Address). I did try to overwrite property in portal.properties but there is nothing come up.

Please kindly give me an advice.

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a Liferay hook as explained [here](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/overriding-a-j-4) to modify `/portal-trunk/portal-web/docroot/html/portal/terms_of_use.jsp` file as per your requirement.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I will try to work on it first and have any questions I would please come back to ask.

Regards,

Comment: Hi Rushikesh,

One more question, is it work with the next content after an user click accept the condition on Terms of use page?

Comment: What exactly do you wanna do after the user accepts the terms of use?

Comment: Hi Rushikesh,
an user will do the normal processes which are verify email address, reset password, and so on. I would like to ask that the layout, which been modified as a hook, will be shown in those processes,or not?

Comment: As you might have noticed, it is Portal jsp, and not part of any portlet page - where you can apply layout. So any change you need to make in the look-n-feel of these portal level screens, you'll have to modify the jsps (like terms_of_use.jsp, update_password.jsp, update_reminder_query.jsp, etc) using hook as I explained.